# How do I access wall posts made by the user in a facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am having trouble accessing the wall of a user. I am making a request to 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userID.'me/feed?access_token='.$access_token

where $access_token contains my access_token.

the strange part is that it is working well when I make the request from the application page... that is: http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/ but when i make the same request in my callback script, it returns only those posts which are made by some application, and it does not show user's own posts like, status messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), i've seen people solving bugs like yours just by changing to the SDK. It usually doesn't require you to pass the access token and supports all methods of the API (i think).

Answer (score 0):

With /me/feed you can access the feed of the currently logged in user. To get the feed of some other user, you need to use their id. I am assuming that's the reason why its working in the application page and not in the script.

Comment: Your access token must have expired because of which it shows only public posts in your script.

Comment: all post are public in the test profile...for which i am running the app...and i am getting a new access token in the callback url itself...specifically for this purpose

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000686936533

Comment: The access token might not have been returned when you are calling from your script.